# Did anyone write custom Affinity function?

Tags: ignite

I want all nodes in a cluster to have equal number data load. With 
default Affinity function it is not happening.

As of now, we have 3 nodes. We use group ID as affinity key, and we have 3 
group IDs (1, 2 and 3). And we limit cache partitions to group IDs. Overall 
nodes=group IDs=cache partitions. So that each node have equal number of 
partitions.

Will it be okay to write custom Affinity function? And 
what will we lose doing so? Did anyone write custom Affinity function?

Comment: An affinity function doesn't change which nodes are used for caching, only the distribution of data from key to partition (so changing the affinity function is not going to help). How are you determining that there are not an equal number of partitions per node? What's your cluster and cache configuration?

Comment: @StephenDarlington I edited the question. Actually I have 3 affinity keys, and 3 nodes. And I wanted all 3 nodes hold exactly 1 affinity key, but it does not happen. What happens is 2 keys on first, 1 key on another , and last one does not have any (random behavior).

Answer (score 0):

The affinity function doesn't *guarantee* an even distribution across all nodes. It's statistical... and three values isn't really enough to make sure the data is "fairly" distributed.

So, yes, writing a new affinity function would work. The downsides being you need to make it fast (it's called a lot) and you'd be hard-coding it to your *current* node topology. What happens when you choose to add a new node? What happens when a node fails? Also, you'd be potentially putting all your data into three partitions which make it harder to scale out (one of the main advantages of Ignite's architecture).

As an alternative, I'd look at your data model. Splitting your data into three chunks is too coarse for things to work automatically.